# Changing QGIS configs and plugins to another partition

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

I need to move all my QGIS configs and plugins to D: instead of C:
I installed QGIS in D: but QGIS is still using some folders in C:

I found [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35517/is-it-possible-to-change-the-plugin-folder-location) in StackExchange but I am unable to reproduce it since I don't understand how he managed to do that.

Could someone explain to me how to?

QGIS version: 2.18.18 
Windows 10